# Dual screen not working (black screen with mouse cursor)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, 19.04

I have a notebook with Ubuntu 19.04 and these video cards:

- Intel® UHD Graphics 630
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070

The notebook screen is working well, but the 2nd display (HDMI) shows only a black screen with a big, ugly mouse cursor. I've tried to update my Nvidia drivers, etc., but as soon as I switch to another driver (I've tried Nvidia 410 and 440) than the default X.org the 2nd display switch off and is not even detected:

[image]

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F10sv00001028sd0000093Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

alice@Alienware:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f10 (rev a1)
```